# Thymeleaf doesn't use formatters for inputs using data-th-field

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I found a problem using Thymeleaf in a Spring Boot application.

Versions:

- Spring Boot 1.3.4 and 1.3.3

My Entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Version
  private int version;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
  private Calendar calendar;

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yy")
  private Date date;

  @NumberFormat(pattern="#0.00000")
  private Double aDouble;

}
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{myEntity}/edit-form", 
     method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String editForm(@PathVariable MyEntity myEntity, Model model)  {
    return "myEntity/edit";
}
```

My *myEntity/edit.html* template:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"
      data-th-object="${myEntity}"
      data-th-action="@{/myEntity/{id}(id=*{id})}">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />

      <div class="form-group"
        data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('calendar')}? 'has-error has-feedback'">
        <label for="calendar" class="col-md-3 control-label">Calendar</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
            data-th-field="*{calendar}"/>
          <span data-th-text="*{{calendar}}"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group"
        data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}? 'has-error has-feedback'">
        <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
            data-th-field="*{date}"/>
          <span data-th-text="*{{date}}"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group"
        data-th-classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('aDouble')}? 'has-error has-feedback'">
        <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">aDouble</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
            data-th-field="*{{aDouble}}"/>
          <span data-th-text="*{{aDouble}}"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

When I try to show this page I get:

```html
<body>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/myEntity/1">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="calendar" class="col-md-3 control-label">Calendar</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="calendar" name="calendar"
            value="java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1451602800000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=&quot;Europe/Madrid&quot;,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=165,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Madrid,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=53,WEEK_OF_MONTH=0,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]" /> 
          <span>01/01/2016</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">Date</label>
       <div class="col-md-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" 
            value="2016-02-01 00:00:00.0" />
         <span>01/02/16</span>
       </div>
      </div>


     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="date" class="col-md-3 control-label">aDouble</label>
       <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="aDouble" name="aDouble" 
             value="0.1" /> 
          <span>0.10000</span>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
  
  </body>
```

As you can see, the values of **all fields aren't formatted** as expected (see `span` which uses the same value through `th-text` attribute) using `toString()` method for all values.

Anybody can help me? Thank's in advance.

EDIT 1: I've create a [new issue about it](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/495)

Comment: What about using double brackets in the inputs as well. According to [this](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/223), that could work.

Comment: I tried but nothing changes (see the input for double: `data-th-field="*{{aDouble}}"`). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was in the *requestMapping* definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{myEntity}/edit-form", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
               produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String editForm(@PathVariable MyEntity myEntity, Model model) {

    }
```

It **requires a `BindingResult` in request context** to get `PropertyEditor` which can transform object value to String. So, including `BindingResult` in *request mapping* definition all works as expected:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{myEntity}/edit-form", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
               produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String editForm(@ModelAttribute MyEntity myEntity, BindingResult result, 
               Model model) {

    }
```

Note that object **must be annotated with `@ModelAttribute`** and **`BindingResult` must be declared just after `@ModelAttribute`**.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score -1):

For date I'd use:

```
${#dates.format(date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm')}
```

and for numbers:

```
${#numbers.formatDecimal(num,3,2,'COMMA')}
```

In documentation it's explained for [numbers](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers) and [dates](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dates).

Comment: This is not a solution. The format should be declared just in one place to assure than Spring MVC binding handles it correctly.